# Liquibase: columnName is required

Tags: database, yaml, database-migration, liquibase

Trying to add a column using Liquibase and I'm stuck.

YAML:

```
databaseChangeLog:
- changeSet:
    id: add-status-1
    author: me
    failOnError: true
    changes:
    - addColumn:
        tableName: CODEENTRY
        columns:
        - column:
          name: STATUS
          type: char(3)
          value: USE
    rollback:
    - dropColumn:
        tableName: CODEENTRY
        columnName: STATUS
```

When starting the application to start the migration, the following error occurres:

```
columnName is required, classpath:db/changelog/initial/20-add-status.yaml::add-status-1::AXRGU02
columnType is required, classpath:db/changelog/initial/20-add-status.yaml::add-status-1::AXRGU02
```

The Liquibase documentation does not state any tags with attributes "columnName" or "columnType" which confuses me even more.

Does anyone know how to fix this or what is wrong with my YAML?

Comment: I have never used YAML, but: The [example in the manual](http://www.liquibase.org/documentation/yaml_format.html) indents the `name:` relative to `column`. Is YAML sensitive to indention?

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name I've checked it using various YAML Parsers. The Indention seems to be correct. (Example: [yaml-online-parser.appspot.com](http://yaml-online-parser.appspot.com), copy above YAML and see JSON output)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your YAML is valid, but not semantically correct.

This part:

```
- column:
  name: STATUS
  type: char(3)
  value: USE
```

defines that this is an entry to a list (`-`), the list item is a mapping because it consists of key-value pairs. The first key-value pair is `column:`. As the following keys are indented the same way as `column:`, *they are treated as succeeding key-value pairs*. So, your key `column:` holds an empty value. What you want is for the key `column:` to hold all the other values as nested mapping. For that, you need to indent the other keys further:

```
- column:
    name: STATUS
    type: char(3)
    value: USE
```

In context:

```
databaseChangeLog:
- changeSet:
    id: add-status-1
    author: me
    failOnError: true
    changes:
    - addColumn:
        tableName: CODEENTRY
        columns:
        - column:
            name: STATUS
            type: char(3)
            value: USE
    rollback:
    - dropColumn:
        tableName: CODEENTRY
        columnName: STATUS
```

Comment: A coworker also pointed this out today. Thank you for your answer.